# Moving files around with a gulp task

Tags: node.js, gulp

So I want to write a gulp task that takes files from my directory and places them in the appropriate directories relative to a provided path. The user will pass me a path to the root directory of their project, like so `gulp move-css --path "C:\Project\"` and my task will move the files to the appropriate locations within that directory. This is my attempt:

```
gulp.task('move-css', function ()
{
  var basePath, i = process.argv.indexOf("--path");
  if(i>-1) {
    basePath = process.argv[i+1];
  }
  console.log('Moving ' + cssFile + ' to ' + basePath + cssRelativePath);

  return gulp.src(cssFile, {base: cssFile})
  .pipe(gulp.dest(basePath + cssRelativePath))
});
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\Project\css
```

Comment: What does `console.log('Moving '...)` returns?

Comment: @mika that just prints out the origin file and the path to which it is being copied for the user to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code, just needed to run the terminal as admin.